# Pandas: Can i predict how many hours my employees are going to work next year based on how many days and hours they worked this year?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, prediction, statsmodels

i'm planning to predict `2023` working hours and days for my employees , each employee have
`DaysCount`= number of days he worked , also   `HoursWorked`= hours he spent in work . The question is ,it's possible ? can i predict next year's stats based on these 2 values ?
any ideas ?

Comment: no, there is almost no way except guessing, if you maybe had those values for some previous years too, then you could model some plausible scenario because you would have more data, now you have basically one data point that can go in basically any direction. ok, maybe you can do the simple thing of calculating the average hours per workday and do sth with that but there are a lot of factors that affect this while you have only one data point

Comment: why assume your employees stay the same every year (they could change or just get older, work in different roles). there is nothing constant in this data so there is no basis for a prediction.

Comment: well, i have these values for the previous four years , what kind of information should i use to make such prediction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, but maybe, It's will be a imprecise solution. But, I'll try to help you to find a solution.

- **Number of attributes:** first of all, a machine learning model requires good features about the person historic to make predictions about their future, use only two attributes could be not the sufficiente to do accurate predictions.
- **Size of training:** another important aspect is the training size, for example, do you have a long historic for all employees? For example, do you have the individual historic, for each employee, for their last decade?
- **Modelling:** An important aspect that you should think is about the modelling. How do you want to train the model? For example, do you will use the january's employee historic to predict the february? Or, do you will use the 2021 employee's historic to predict 2022, and use this model to predict 2023? Do you have any others features to feed the model? What explain the number of days and hours worked? For example, the hours worked could be explained by the day week, this means that, if you work in a restaurant (for example), you can work more in the weekends. So, it's important to model know the week day. The days count could be afect by the vacations/hollydays, so, include these informations in the data should be very important. After that, you must consider how you will split the data into training and test. Do you will use the historic of the last seven-days to predict the next one day? Or, you will use the last month historic to predict the next month?

Comment: Hey, I'm Data Scientist, may I help you? Look me at Linkedin: https://www.linkedin.com/in/italo-de-pontes-oliveira/

Comment: hey italo , i have data for the previous 4 years for every employee , a month of work equals  22 days , and if it's possible i want to use this 2022 3 months data to predict the next month

Comment: Hum, I think you should look for something like "temporal sliding window" to make forward prediction. This may help you.